# How can I expand' a Flash Movie to Move Other Objects out of it's way on the HTML Page

Tags: flash, html, expand, border

I have a question regarding flash. I am an intermediate flash user. Basically, I want a flash movie to expand like this homepage video, when the user clicks on the go button: http://www.vitsoe.com/en/gb

1. Is it possible to "expand" the borders of a flash animation in such a way, and if so, how do I set this up in flash?
2. Is it possible to have the drop-down menu displace the content below it on a html site? i.e. a 250-pixel high banner drops from the original flash piece, is it possible to have the rest of the page move down 250-pixels as well?

Any help would be immensely appreciated as I can't seem to find a straight forward flash tutorial to assist me further.

Comment: both are yes, if you want some snippets show the code you already have, so we could provide some support.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave looks like a mix of Javascript and Flash.

The first part, i.e. the image moving out and the content under the image sliding down would be a Javascript function , probably using JQuery as the links in the source seem to indicate.

At the end of this action , the flash movie appears giving the impression of a window expanding.

As far as I see it, this is more about Javascript than Actionscript.

Comment: But do you know of anyway I could do this all in Flash?

Comment: To do it all exclusively in Flash , I'm afraid not... The reason being that to push down the HTML content, I think you would need to use Javascript.